# How to upload files to elasticbeanstalk for app configuration?

Tags: node.js, configuration, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a **nodejs** app in **elasticbeanstalk**, and I need to configure an external service with a json config file.

To configure the app I need to set and env variable that has the path to the configuration file. For example...

`export SERVICE_CREDENTIALS_PATH="/home/user/config.json"`

How can I upload the config.json file to elasticbeanstalk and have it there for every new version of the app deployed?

Answer (score 1):

Elastic Beanstalk extracts your application source bundle to `/var/app/current`. If you include the file (`config.json`) in the root of your application, then you should be able to set `SERVICE_CREDENTIALS_PATH` to `/var/app/current/config.json`.